# macOS - virtualbox xcode connect

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, usb, virtualbox

I have installed macOS inside virtual-box, but then I connect my iPhone 6. It works and I can compile and install an IOS app to my iPhone 6.

steps:

> Devices -> USB -> apple inc. iPhone - (I can't connect the iphone.)

Then I tried to connect another device (iPhone 7).

I got this error here:

> Failed to create a proxy device for the USB (Error VERR_READ_ERROR)

How can I connect another device. Have someone any idea how I can fix this issues?

Comment: how did you solve it?

Comment: i did not solve it.